# @ConfigurationProperties with placeholders inside yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an environment specific property defined in `application-{env}.properties`.

***application-dev.properties:***

```
cm.security.power-users-group=fCmNonProdPowerUse
```

I have a YAML configuration which maps groups to permissions:

***roles-mapping.yml:***

```
cm:
  security:
    mapping:
      roles:
        ${cm.security.power-users-group}:
          - 'DATASET_UPLOAD'
```

I want to use the above YAML file with `@ConfigurationProperties`. Have it as follows:

```
@Getter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:roles-mapping.yml", ignoreInvalidFields = false, ignoreUnknownFields = false, prefix = "cm.security.mapping")
public class RoleConfig {

    private Map<String, List<Permissions>> roles = new HashMap<>();
}
```

This is unable to resolve the placeholder inside yaml file saying:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'roles[${cm].security[power-users-group}][0]'

As soon as i replace the `${..}` placeholder with a direct value everything works.

So is there a way to resolve placeholder from a `.properties` file inside YAML?

Comment: Try to use @cm-security-power-users-group@, it is work for me

Comment: Seems this is a limitation. The flattening process obviously doesn't recognize this as placeholder but even if it did the property would be `cm.security.mapping.roles.${cm.security.power-users-group}[0]` and if I try that in property file it is not resolved either. Seems to me it's by design.